# Filled Maps in Power BI not working (despite normal maps working!!)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

would like to thank you advance.

New to Power BI but have found that filled Maps does not working despite working on same data with normal Maps.

I am trying to produce a filled map using US States (full state name used).

Could this be a bug with Power BI (as this seems very intuitive for it not to work) or am I missing something?

Screenshots below:
1. Screenshot shows that Maps is working and is picking up on the State names.

[image]

2. Screenshot shows when chart type is switched to Filled Maps, State data is not represented as a filled map.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY1pa.png]

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simon were you ever able to get the filled maps working? If so do you care to share what you did? I have attempted and am not able to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this post](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-tips-and-tricks-for-power-bi-map-visualizations/).

Things to try:

- Provide some measure or value to the `Color saturation` field of your filled map visualisation.
- Set the data category of your `State` property to `State/Province` (Modelling tab)
- Change your state names to use geo location terms, e.g. `Washington`->`Washington, DC`.
- Include country name: `Southampton`->`Southampton, England`.
- Specify latitude/longitude as well as above.